# event while choosing a specific option with select2

Tags: jquery-select2

Im using select2.js and i want to add an option that while choose that specific one, it will run a JS function or link to a web.

This is my js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".client-select").select2({
    placeholder: "choose client",
    allowClear: true
});


});
```

Comment: Add your html also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add select2:select listener which is similar to onChange,which will trigger function everytime you select a value from options.
Here it is,

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".client-select").select2({
    placeholder: "choose client",
    allowClear: true
   });

    $('.client-select').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var data = e.params.data;
    if(data=='your_value'){
     yourFunction();
     }
   });

});
```

Comment: In my html code the option is: <option value="new" >create new customer</option>

Comment: It will fetch the value field from  `<option value='yourValur'></option>'

Comment: Do you want to get the value=new, on function trigger, if I am right?

Comment: Then I need to see your html also. Did you added the class `client-select` to your select tag

Comment: <select class="client-select" name='client_id' style="width: 50%">
   <option value="new">new</option>
   </select>

Comment: Html looks fine...add console.log to see what you get in e.params.data and check if you are properly using `data` in your function.

Comment: Thanks! i used console.log, and realize that i need to use: e.params.data.id to get the id

Comment: Cool, accept the answer by clicking right tick on it, if it helps you. Thanks.